# Analog FM & IQ modulation

Tags: frequency-modulation, quadrature

I am exploring the possibilities of IQ modulator. I want to do analog FM modulation (range $0$ to $5 ~ kHz$) using IQ modulator.
So far, I can modulate the signal digitally inside of the STM32 processor by the following equation

$$I = \cos \left( - M_{i} \cos \left( 2 \pi f_{m} t \right) \right) \tag{1} \label{1}$$

where $M_{i}$ is the modulation index, $\sin$ wave as input baseband signal and $Q = \sin \left( -M_{i} \cos \left( 2 \pi f_{m} t \right) \right)$.
Modulating frequency is $100 ~ Hz$, deviation $2400 ~ Hz$, sampling frequency $48 ~ kHz$.
I am using a codec to generate the $I$ and $Q$ signal as shown below.

[image]

Then DAC output goes to single ended to differential amplifier with 5th Bessel filter and then goes to IQ modulator LTC5599.
The IQ modulator output is directly captured by a spectrum analyser.

[image]

However, when I demodulate (using a ZVL FM demodulator) the signal, I see a lot of harmonic content.

[image]

[image]

I think, I am missing something.
Very new in this area. Any kind of suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: The FM signal generated by a sinusoidal modulating signal indeed contains a quite lot of harmonics, especially when the ratio of $M_i/2\pi f_m$ (with your notation) is large. Try to use a low-pass filter applied to the demodulated signal to filter out more residual harmonics.

Comment: thank for your feedback. Adding low pass filter would not help because my useable frequency range 0 to 5kHz, so i can place a lpf of 5.5 khz which will not improve my lower order harmonics. However, 
The modulating signal can be improved right?

Comment: You said "when I demodulate (using a ZVL FM demodulator) the signal, I see a lot of harmonic content." Do you mean that the demodulated signal has a lot of harmonics ? The purpose of the demodulation is to recover the modulating signal (100 Hz in your case) used in the modulation. So, I think you may use a low-pass filter to remove the residual harmonics in the demodulated (100 Hz) signal output from the demodulator.

Comment: I suggest taking the same spectrum you show of your signal prior to the FM mod and demod for comparison. At this point you don’t know how much of what you see is contributed from your signal vs distortion in your processing.

Comment: I understand your point. Other than software fm modulation, there are not so much things that can distort the signal.the path is as follow: stm32->codec->differencial amplifier +low pass filter->ltc5599-> spectrum analyzer. The high frequency rf generated signal has phase noise -90db/hz at 10khz. I think the modulated signal is the cause for the distortion, but out of idea how I can improve it.

Comment: @DanBoschen i took the modulating signal (i & Q part) in the spectrum and the signal is really distorted because of the modulation . I see direct similarities between the I&Q spectrum and demodulated spectrum. So, it is clear to see the distortion is coming from modulating signal. Now the question is , is there any way to do the FM modulation that will have less impact.

Comment: I’m not sure it is specific to your approach with I and Q but rather the quality of your signal coming out of your  DAC. Have you tried evaluating the spectrum of a single test tone out of I and out of Q, separately to be sure you are getting the spurious free dynamic range you would need (and that matches the datasheet for what you should expect)?

Comment: @DanBoschen, first i thought the same. Mathematically created sinc wave in the stm32 and placing to the output of dac with a buffer i got SFDR of more than 70db which is expected from a 12 bit dac. But with the modulated wave(I data) i got only 10db SFDR which is a big difference. I do not know which SFDR i should expect from the modulating wave.